# MySQL backward lookup with forward result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario where I need to obtain a set of results in **ascending** order but only given the last ID in the **descending** sequence.

[image]

The order will always be sequentially ascending as the ID is auto generated however, I cannot guarantee that ID sequence is unbroken. i.e. I cannot say 8 - 3 = 5 therefore do a forward lookup from 5.

What is the most efficient was of achieving this. If possibly I want to avoid manipulating the collection in the application logic but can as a last resort.

Comment: Show us your table structure/data and highlight what information we could use to impose the ordering you want.

Comment: The problem is that the table structure changes. This is an implementation of cursor based paging. The information supplied is the only common data across all the tables.

Comment: Without table structure I doubt you will get an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why do you need to table structure? The only relevant column is the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with an inner select:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM your_table
  WHERE id <= X
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT Y
) d
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own `rownum` with query and apply `mod` to get every 3rd record regardless of it's id, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT id, name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as `num`
   FROM test, (SELECT @rownum := 0) a ) b
WHERE b.num % 3 = 0;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3158713/3/0)**.

Comment: This would pick one row every X, not X rows from the specified ID, as OP asks.